# ActiveMQ: Using Proxy Broker to connect to a backend network of brokers

Tags: java, activemq-classic

I'm trying to use the proxy connectors to redirect the traffic of a broker towards another broker. 
I need to cope with authentication through certificates in my scenario. 
When I use a bind uri of the type `nio+ssl://192.168.1.5:61619`, the communication is perfect. 
When I use a bind uri of the type `nio+ssl://192.168.1.5:61619?needClientAuth=true`, the client cannot start the connection.

Am I missing anything?

This is the code of my Proxy, composed of two classes.

ActiveMQBrokerActivator.java:

```
public class ActiveMQBrokerActivator {

private static BrokerService broker;
private static SslContext customSslContext;

private final static String certificatesFolder = "config" + File.separator + "certificates" + File.separator + 
        "amq" + File.separator;
private final static String broker_ks_file = certificatesFolder + "broker.ks";
private final static String broker_ts_file = certificatesFolder + "broker.ts";

private static String trustorepswd = "MyStrongPwd";  //TODO: change with your password  
private static String keystorepswd = trustorepswd;   

private static int jmxConnectorPort = 1098;

private static String jmxDomainName = "proxybroker";

private String proxyBrokerAddr = "10.0.3.41"; //TODO: change with your local IP 
private String remoteBrokerAddr = "10.0.3.13"; //TODO: change with IP of the remote broker

private String[] proxyNames = new String[] { "proxy_nio", "proxy_nio_ssl", "proxy_tcp", "proxy_tcp_ssl" };
private int[] proxyBrokerPorts = new int[] { 61716, 61719, 61726, 61729 };
private String[] proxyParams = new String[] { "", "?needClientAuth=true", "", "?needClientAuth=true" };
//private String[] proxyParams = new String[] { "", "", "", "" };
private String[] protocols = new String[] { "nio", "nio+ssl", "tcp", "ssl" };
private int[] remoteBrokerPorts = new int[] { 61616, 61619, 61626, 61629 };

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ActiveMQBrokerActivator activator = new ActiveMQBrokerActivator();
    activator.init();

    String input = "";
    while(!input.equalsIgnoreCase("quit")) {
        System.out.print("Type 'reload' to reload certificates; 'quit' to exit");

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        input = br.readLine();

        if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("reload"))
            ActiveMQBrokerActivator.updateSSLcontext();
    }
}


public void init() throws Exception {   
    System.out.println("Starting ActiveMQ Broker...");

    //setup broker:
    Properties properties = System.getProperties();
    broker = new BrokerService();
    broker.setUseJmx(true);
    broker.setBrokerName(jmxDomainName);

    //set JMX connector port and domain name in order not to retrieve the correct info 
    broker.getManagementContext().setConnectorPort(jmxConnectorPort);
    broker.getManagementContext().setJmxDomainName(jmxDomainName);

    //set key-store and trust-store properties:
    properties.put("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", broker_ks_file);
    properties.put("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", keystorepswd); 
    properties.put("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", broker_ts_file);
    properties.put("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", trustorepswd); 

    System.out.println("      - keystore is " + properties.getProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore"));
    System.out.println("      - truststore is " + properties.getProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore"));

    System.out.println("Setting custom SSLContext for dynamic cert loading...");
    customSslContext = getSslContext();
    broker.setSslContext(customSslContext);
    System.out.println("...done!");

    //Add proxy connectors to the broker:
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        addProxyConn(protocols[i] + "://" + proxyBrokerAddr + ":" + proxyBrokerPorts[i] + proxyParams[i], 
                proxyNames[i], protocols[i] + "://" + remoteBrokerAddr + ":" + remoteBrokerPorts[i]);
    }

    tuning();

    // broker must be activated here if we want to add plugins...
    broker.start();
    System.out.println("Broker AMQ is starting...");
    broker.waitUntilStarted();
    while(!broker.isStarted());
    System.out.println("Broker AMQ started: " + broker.getAdminView().getVMURL() + 
            " broker id: " + broker.getAdminView().getBrokerId() + " v. " + broker.getAdminView().getBrokerVersion());

    /* TimeStampingBrokerPlugin handles the possible miss alignments among broker and producers 
     * timestamps. Besides, it overides the zero-TTL specified by the producers
     */
    TimeStampingBrokerPlugin tsbp = new TimeStampingBrokerPlugin();     
    tsbp.setZeroExpirationOverride(200000);        

    tsbp.installPlugin(broker.getBroker());
    tsbp.start();

    System.out.println("Broker [" + broker.getBrokerName() + "] has correctly started");   
}

private static void addProxyConn(String bindUri, String name, String remoteUri) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Adding AMQ proxy connector...");
    ProxyConnector proxy_conn = new ProxyConnector();
    proxy_conn.setBind(new URI(bindUri));
    proxy_conn.setName(name);
    proxy_conn.setProxyToLocalBroker(false);
    proxy_conn.setRemote(new URI(remoteUri));

    System.out.println("    AMQ proxy connector " +  proxy_conn.getName() + " has been added successfully.");
    broker.addProxyConnector(proxy_conn);
}


private static synchronized void updateSSLcontext(){
    try {
        ReloadableX509TrustManager tm = (ReloadableX509TrustManager)customSslContext.getTrustManagersAsArray()[0];
        tm.reloadTrustManager();
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.err.println("Error while reloading trust manager due to " + e.toString());
    }
}

private SslContext getSslContext() throws Exception {
    KeyManagerFactory kmf = 
            KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());  
    KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("jks");
    KeyManager[] keystoreManagers = null;

    ks.load(new FileInputStream(new File(broker_ks_file)), keystorepswd.toCharArray());
    kmf.init(ks, keystorepswd.toCharArray());
    keystoreManagers = kmf.getKeyManagers();

    TrustManager[] trustStoreManagers = new TrustManager[] {
            new ReloadableX509TrustManager(broker_ts_file, trustorepswd)
    };

    SslContext context = new SslContext(keystoreManagers, trustStoreManagers, null);
    return context;
}


private void tuning() {
    /* We want to delete destinations that are inactive for a period of time. Since ActiveMQ version 5.4.0, 
     * it's possible to do that using destination policy entries and broker attribute 
     * schedulePeriodForDestinationPurge > 0
     */
    broker.setSchedulePeriodForDestinationPurge(120000); //2 minutes

    /* This is to set how the broker should dispatch outgoing messages: 
     * At the time being, PolicyEntry items do not aggregate (see at
     * http://activemq.2283324.n4.nabble.com/Do-policy-map-entries-aggregate-tt4297601.html#a4300231)
     * There is a best match, and the default takes the unmatched case: all topics starting with 
     * "stream." will use the stream_entry policy while all other topics will default on std_entry
     * policy. 
     */
    PolicyMap map = new PolicyMap();
    PolicyEntry std_entry = new PolicyEntry();
    PolicyEntry stream_entry = new PolicyEntry();

    // All topics:
    std_entry.setTopic(">");
    stream_entry.setTopic("stream.>");
    std_entry.setDispatchPolicy(new StrictOrderDispatchPolicy());

    std_entry.setOptimizedDispatch(true);
    stream_entry.setOptimizedDispatch(true);

    final long EXPIRE_MSG_PERIOD = 200000; //200 seconds
    final long STREAM_EXPIRE_MSG_PERIOD = 3000; //3 seconds

    /* Sets the strategy to calculate the maximum number of messages that are allowed 
     * to be pending on consumers (in addition to their prefetch sizes). 
     * Once the limit is reached, non-durable topics can then start discarding old 
     * messages. This allows us to keep dispatching messages to slow consumers while 
     * not blocking fast consumers and discarding the messages oldest first.
     */
    final long PENDING_MSG_LIMIT = 200000; //after this, start check TTL
    ConstantPendingMessageLimitStrategy pendMsgStrategy = new ConstantPendingMessageLimitStrategy();
    pendMsgStrategy.setLimit((int)PENDING_MSG_LIMIT);
    std_entry.setPendingMessageLimitStrategy(pendMsgStrategy);

    final long STREAM_PENDING_MSG_LIMIT = 200000; //after this, start check TTL
    ConstantPendingMessageLimitStrategy streamPendMsgStrategy = new ConstantPendingMessageLimitStrategy();
    streamPendMsgStrategy.setLimit((int)STREAM_PENDING_MSG_LIMIT);
    stream_entry.setPendingMessageLimitStrategy(streamPendMsgStrategy);

    /* See: http://activemq.apache.org/producer-flow-control.html
     * With producer flow control disabled, messages for slow consumers will be off-lined to
     * temporary storage by default, enabling the producers and the rest of the consumers to
     * run  at  a  much  faster  rate:
     */ 
    std_entry.setProducerFlowControl(false);

    /* See http://activemq.apache.org/manage-durable-subscribers.html
     * Some applications send message with specified time to live. If those messages are kept on 
     * the broker for the offline durable subscriber we need to remove them when they reach their 
     * expiry time. Just as AMQ does with queues, now AMQ checks for those messages every 
     * EXPIRE_MSG_PERIOD.
     * This configuration complements the Timestampplugin (http://activemq.apache.org/timestampplugin.html)
     */
    std_entry.setExpireMessagesPeriod((int)EXPIRE_MSG_PERIOD); 
    stream_entry.setProducerFlowControl(false);
    stream_entry.setExpireMessagesPeriod((int)STREAM_EXPIRE_MSG_PERIOD); 

    /* This will check for inactive destination and it will delete all queues (gcInactiveDestinations option) 
     * if they are empty for "OfflineDurableSubscriberTimeout" millis  
     */     
    std_entry.setGcInactiveDestinations(true);
    std_entry.setInactiveTimoutBeforeGC(1200000);
    stream_entry.setGcInactiveDestinations(true);
    stream_entry.setInactiveTimoutBeforeGC(1200000);

    map.setDefaultEntry(std_entry);

    LinkedList<PolicyEntry> policies = new LinkedList<PolicyEntry>();
    policies.add(stream_entry);
    map.setPolicyEntries(policies);

    broker.setDestinationPolicy(map);

    // Set memory manager: refer to the following links for further documentation:
    // - http://activemq.2283324.n4.nabble.com/StoreUsage-TempUsage-and-MemoryUsage-td2356734.html
    // And also (NOT OFFIAL but rather clear explanations):
    // - http://tmielke.blogspot.it/2011/02/observations-on-activemqs-temp-storage.html
    // - http://java.dzone.com/articles/activemq-understanding-memory
    // Default values (see http://activemq.apache.org/producer-flow-control.html#ProducerFlowControl-Systemusage): 
    //      - Default Memory limit is 64 mb
    //      - Default Temp Usage limit is 100 gb
    //      - Default Store Usage limit is 10 gb
    SystemUsage usage = broker.getSystemUsage();

    long memLimit = 1024L * 1024L, 
         tempLimit = 1024L * 1024L, 
         storeLimit = 1024L * 1024L;

    memLimit *= 64;
    tempLimit *= 10000;
    storeLimit *= 50000;

    MemoryUsage memUsage = usage.getMemoryUsage();
    memUsage.setLimit(memLimit);
    usage.setMemoryUsage(memUsage);

    TempUsage tmpUsage = usage.getTempUsage();
    tmpUsage.setLimit(tempLimit);
    usage.setTempUsage(tmpUsage);

    StoreUsage storeUsage = usage.getStoreUsage();
    storeUsage.setLimit(storeLimit);
    usage.setStoreUsage(storeUsage);

    boolean sendFailIfNoSpace=false;
    if(sendFailIfNoSpace)
        usage.setSendFailIfNoSpace(sendFailIfNoSpace);

    broker.setSystemUsage(usage);

    manageAdditionalPolicies();
}   

private void manageAdditionalPolicies() {
    PolicyEntry std_entry = new PolicyEntry();
    std_entry.setTopic(">");
    std_entry.setEnableAudit(false);
    ConditionalNetworkBridgeFilterFactory bff=new ConditionalNetworkBridgeFilterFactory();
    bff.setReplayWhenNoConsumers(true);
    std_entry.setNetworkBridgeFilterFactory(bff);

    LinkedList<PolicyEntry> policies = new LinkedList<PolicyEntry>();
    policies.add(std_entry);
    broker.getDestinationPolicy().setPolicyEntries(policies);       
}

protected static int getJmxConnectorPort() {
    return jmxConnectorPort;
}

protected static String getJmxDomainName() {
    return jmxDomainName;
}
}
```

ReloadableX509TrustManager.java:

```
public class ReloadableX509TrustManager implements X509TrustManager {

private final String trustStorePath;
private final String tspassword;
private X509TrustManager trustManager;

public ReloadableX509TrustManager(String tspath, String tspassword) throws Exception {
    this.trustStorePath = tspath;
    this.tspassword = tspassword;
    reloadTrustManager();
}

@Override
public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
    try{
        trustManager.checkClientTrusted(chain, authType);
    }catch(Exception e){
        try{
            reloadTrustManager();
        }catch(Exception ex){
            throw new CertificateException(ex);
        }
        trustManager.checkClientTrusted(chain, authType);
    }
}

@Override
public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
    try {
        trustManager.checkServerTrusted(chain, authType);
    } catch (CertificateException cx) {
        try{
            reloadTrustManager();
        }catch(Exception e){
            throw new CertificateException(e);
        }
        trustManager.checkServerTrusted(chain, authType);
    }
}

@Override
public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
    X509Certificate[] issuers = trustManager.getAcceptedIssuers();
    return issuers;
}

public void reloadTrustManager() throws Exception {

    // load keystore from specified cert store (or default)
    KeyStore ts = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
    InputStream in = new FileInputStream(trustStorePath);
    try { 
        ts.load(in, null); 
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally { 
        in.close(); 
    }

    // initialize a new TMF with the ts we just loaded
    TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
    tmf.init(ts);

    // acquire X509 trust manager from factory
    TrustManager tms[] = tmf.getTrustManagers();
    for (int i = 0; i < tms.length; i++) {
        if (tms[i] instanceof X509TrustManager) {
            trustManager = (X509TrustManager)tms[i];
            return;
        }
    }
    throw new NoSuchAlgorithmException("No X509TrustManager in TrustManagerFactory");
}

protected void addServerCertAndReload(X509Certificate cert) {
    try {
        // import the cert into file trust store
        File tsfile = new File(this.trustStorePath);
        java.io.FileInputStream fis = null;
        if(tsfile.exists()){
            fis = new FileInputStream(tsfile);
        }else{
            System.err.println("Truststore " + tsfile.getAbsolutePath() + " does not exist!");
            throw new Exception("Truststore " +tsfile.getAbsolutePath() + " does not exist!");
        }
        KeyStore ts = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());

        char[] keystorePass = this.tspassword.toCharArray();
        try { 
            ts.load(fis, keystorePass); 
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally { 
            fis.close(); 
        }

        ts.setCertificateEntry("", cert);

        ts.store(new FileOutputStream(this.trustStorePath), keystorePass);

        reloadTrustManager();
    } catch (Exception ex) { 
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```